# How do I get all records from tableA with a left outer join and a where condition on tableB?

Tags: sql

Basically, what I want is if there is a record in tableB of type 'X' I want to see it, otherwise I don't, but I want all records from tableA.

I know I could accomplish this by putting the tableB.type = 'X' in the LEFT OUTER JOIN ON clause, but I can't do that because I'm limited to using only the where condition because I'm using a restricted query manager of a program I won't name, but I definitely hate. :)

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ON tableA.ID = tableB.ID
WHERE tableB.type = 'X'
```

How do I accomplish this?

***EDIT***

I've tried this, but I still don't get all records from tableA. I'm testing this on SQL server to avoid waiting for long periods for my query to run on the production system. I'm pretty sure the production system is using Oracle if that helps.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA LEFT OUTER JOIN ON tableA.ID = tableB.ID
WHERE tableB.type = 'X' OR tableB.type IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

Check for `null`s in tableB:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA LEFT OUTER JOIN ON tableA.ID = tableB.ID
WHERE tableB.type = 'X'
OR tableB.type IS NULL
```

That will get you everything from both tables when the join matches, and everything from tableA when there's no corresponding record in tableB.

If `type` can be `null` naturally, you'll want to change the condition to something more sound:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA LEFT OUTER JOIN ON tableA.ID = tableB.ID
WHERE tableB.type = 'X'
OR tableB.ID IS NULL
```

Assuming `ID` is the primary key and cannot be `null` naturally, that will get the same result.

Comment: In these situations I always try to compare the primary key to "IS NULL"- which is the second SQL snippet in this answer.

Comment: This will not work in SQL Server. The where clause citing tableb changes the join internally to an inner join. When I added the where clause it brought me only records which had null in the field I was looking at. If I put it on the ID field I still got the wrong answer

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you have access to the database, or if you have to query tableB specifically due to some other restriction, but you could always create a view of table b called tableBTypeX where the view is restricted to only those rows with type = x. Then you could left outer join against tableBTypeX . In your query, the join columns are ID columns, so they probably have indexes, making the query fine in terms of speed. In the case where the join columns are not indexed, joining against the view would be more efficient, because fewer rows are joined against, and joining against unindexed rows usually requires a full table scan, making it a much more time consuming query.

Comment: Instead of a full blown view, you might be able to use an inline view.

Answer (score 1):

You can join against the "type X" records from tableB exclusively by amending the join condition:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  tableA 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ON 
    tableA.ID = tableB.ID  
    AND tableB.type = 'X'
```

Comment: He specifically said it cannot be done in the ON clause, but must be done in the WHERE clause.

Comment: The OP mentions he can't amend the join statement.

Answer (score 1):

Is UNION possible?

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ON tableA.ID = tableB.ID
WHERE tableB.type = 'X'

UNION

SELECT *
FROM tableA
```

... or a CTE? Not sure how the name tableB would resolve though and can't test...

```
;WITH tableB AS
(
    SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE type = 'X'
)
SELECT *
FROM
    tableA 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tableB ON tableA.ID = tableB.ID
```